# Convert text in list to data frame

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list, and for example its second element is:

```
datf[2]
[[1]]
                              topicML                                gender
                                    "0"                                "male"
                             sentiment                               topicV 
                                   "0"                                    "0"
```

I try to convert that second element of the list to a data frame wit the code `a <- as.data.frame(datf[2])`, but it´s not working because the list is not in the proper way so that the code works.

So , as we see, each element of the list is a text and I want to convert it to a data frame with the following structure:

```
> s
  topicML gender sentiment topicV
1       0   male         0      0
```

How Can I do that?

Comment: probably should paste the output of `dput(datf)`

Answer (score 0):

you may try the following:

```
do.call(rbind, datf)
```